# Cam case Raspberry - PI NOIR V2 - how to add infrared

Tags: raspbian

I have this camera case with a 3b+ and PI Noir V2 cam and Infrared detector.

[image]

Now I really would like to add infrared to be able to see when completely dark. Is that possible in some way?

Answer (score 0):

https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F121458002700 the IR modules are very cheap on eBay and could be powered either from the R-Pi or a standalone battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera needs some light to capture an image. If you want to capture images *in the dark* using a PI Noir, you have to illuminate the scene with infrared (IR) lighting. This will you give a sense of seeing in the dark, since the PI Noir camera can see IR and you can't.

The [Bright PI](https://www.pi-supply.com/product/bright-pi-bright-white-ir-camera-light-raspberry-pi/) is designed especially for the PI, and can be used to provide IR light. Unfortunately, I can't find any serious documentation about it (so there is no way to know if it will fit your case, and no information about the light power output).

Please note that any IR lighting will do.